# React native mapview how do i get user coordinates the easy way

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, maps, coordinates

Is there any way of getting user coordinates in react native mapview?

I am trying to make a polyline between user and marker, but I don't know how. It would be much better if it would not use component did mount or redux, but if there is no way can you please include details of how to use it because I'm a beginner.

My code is:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MapView, { PROVIDER_GOOGLE, Polyline } from 'react-native-maps';

import Rectangle from './spotInfo'

export default class App extends React.Component {
  
  state = {
    spotName: "No Spot Selected!", spotDesc: "Select a spot to show info.", long: "", lat: "" ,
    currentSpot: {
      latitude: 52.5200066,
      longitude: 13.404954
    },
    Gotospot: {
      latitude: 50.1109221,
      longitude: 8.6821267
    },
  }
  
  updateState = (name, desc, long, lat) => {
    console.log(position.coords.latitude)
    this.setState({ spotName: name, spotDesc: desc, long: long, lat: lat })}
  MarkerPress = (spotName, spotDesc, long, lat) => this.updateState(spotName, spotDesc, long, lat)
  render() {
  
    
  
    return (
        <MapView
          style={{ flex: 1 }}
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          showsUserLocation
          initialRegion={{
          latitude: 47.497913,
          longitude: 19.040236,
          latitudeDelta: 0.2,
          longitudeDelta: 0.2}}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          followUserLocation={true}
          >
          <MapView.Marker coordinate={{latitude: 47.497913, longitude: 19.040236}} onPress={(e) => {e.stopPropagation(); this.MarkerPress('Deak Ter', 'An Awesome skatepark with a bowl.' , '47.497913', '19.040236')}} />
          <MapView.Marker coordinate={{latitude: 47.487913, longitude: 19.030236}} onPress={(e) => {e.stopPropagation(); this.MarkerPress('Deak Ter2', 'An Awesome skatepark without a bowl.' , '47.487913', '19.030236')}} />
          <Polyline coordinates={[this.state.currentSpot, this.state.Gotospot]} />
          <Rectangle spotName = {this.state.spotName} spotDesc={this.state.spotDesc}/>
        </MapView>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're right in putting the props `showsUserLocation={true}`already but if you're using iOS you have tu put a new item in your ``Ìnfo.plist``` as you can see in the image below: [image: showsuserLocation]

To get the coordinates latitude and longitude you have the prop `onUserLocationChange`. It returns a callback when the map figures out the user position: [image: onUserLocationChange]

For more details you can see directly in the docs of [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/blob/master/docs/mapview.md).

Waiting for your feedback. Thx :). If you have more doubts please feel free to ask.

Comment: Hi thanks for responding so soon, i dont have an info.plist file inside my project. I also dont know where to put that file.if you could include some mor information of these and how to add a new item into it, i am a beginner and have never done something like this. Thanks for helping